# GitLab Runner won't connect to other ec2, via scp ERROR: debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

Tags: deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently, I'm trying to use a docker image gitlab file inorder to connect to my production server and overwrite my code within the production on deployment. While I can ssh from my local machine with the private key given, whenever I try to copy the private key as a variable and connect I consistently get the error of:

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
...
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
 Host key verification failed.
 lost connection
```

I've verified that the /dev/tty address exists on both machines and that my .pem can be read appropriately on the gitlab runner post copying, I've established appropriate permissions with chmod and also have tried multiple permutations of calling the scp script. I'm currently running my connection within the before_script of my gitlab.yml file to avoid the delay of building the docker images within my file and the relevant portion is enclosed below.

**EDIT: /dev/tty also has the correct permissions, I've viewed the previous stack overflow posts related to this issue and they either weren't relevant to the problem or weren't the solution**

```
image: docker:19.03.5

services:
    - docker:19.03.1-dind

before_script:
    - docker info
    - apk update
    - apk add --no-cache openssh
    - touch $SSH_KEY_NAME
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" > "./$SSH_KEY_NAME"
    - chmod 700 $SSH_KEY_NAME
    - ls -la /dev/tty
    - scp -v -P 22 $SSH_KEY_NAME -i $SSH_KEY_NAME $PROD_USER@$SERVER_URL:.
```

Apologies if it feels dumb, but I have little experience within the technical nature of private key setup from another machine, currently I'm unsure if I need to link the private key within my gitlab runner in a specific way? If it's possible that the echo isn't saving the .pem as a private key. My IP inbound for the aws instance is set for all traffic on port 22, and copying this key and connecting from my PC works fine. It's just the runner that has problems. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found to this is to either run an ubuntu gitlab-image and manually call docker inside it with a volume tied to ssh or use a aws instance with a password to gitlab secrets if you're hardpressed on the dind image in gitlab. Neither is truly optimal, but due to the containerization's effectiveness in isolation, you have to resolve it in one of the two method's.